# Caracteres extraños al recuperar archivo json desde jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un problema al llenar una dropdown list.
Los datos los obtengo desde un archivo json.
Los registros con acentos o eñes no se representan correctamente.

[image: Concretamente se ven así]

El código para llenar el desplegable es este:

```
 let ddlCodigoIdiomaNAV = $('#CodigoIdioma');
 ddlCodigoIdiomaNAV.empty();
 ddlCodigoIdiomaNAV.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Seleccionar idioma</option>');
 ddlCodigoIdiomaNAV.prop('selectedIndex', 0);
 let urlCodigoIdiomaNAV = '/Json/Codigo-idioma-list.json';
 $.getJSON(urlCodigoIdiomaNAV, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
       ddlCodigoIdiomaNAV.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.Codigo).text(entry.Nombre));
    });
 });
```

Comment: Es un problema de codificación. Es posible que el archivo json este guardado como ANSI en lugar de UTF-8? Abrelo con el bloc de notas por ejemplo, pulsa en guardar como, fijate que abajo sale la codificación, guardalo como utf-8 y prueba. Si no, es un problema en el código.

Comment: Gracias Pikoh. Justamente era eso. Si lo pones como respuesta la aceptaré.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si hablamos de archivos, normalmente suele ser un problema de codificación del mismo. Es posible que el archivo json este guardado como ANSI en lugar de UTF-8.

Una solución rápida es abrir el archivo con el bloc de notas, pulsar en `Guardar como`, y en la parte inferior aparece con desplegable con la codificación. Hay que guardarlo como `UTF-8`.